# Is it possible to add design-time properties to custom controls

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield

We have developed a custom control in monotouch (inherited from UITextField, but that shouldn't matter) in order to provide pure numeric data entry.

What we would like to do now is add some properties (such as the number of decimal positions, min value, max value) that can be set at design time in xcode.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode does not support editing custom properties of classes in the designer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I have been extremely disappointed in the apple development ecosystem, but at least monotouch provides some light in the darkness.